How to select 3 rows, using offset & limit, but merge rows with same ID
SELECT message."id"  AS "id"
     , message."transactionId"  AS "transactionId"
     , "ids"
     , message"createdAt" AS "createdAt"
FROM message as message
     JOIN (
         SELECT
              "transactionId",
              "createdAt",
              array_agg(thisMessage.id) as "ids",
               min(thisMessage.id::text)::uuid as "id"
          FROM message as thisMessage
          WHERE thisMessage."groupId" = 'a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e'
          GROUP BY "transactionId", "createdAt"
          ORDER BY createdAt DESC
          OFFSET 0 LIMIT 9
      ) as groupM
            ON message."id" = groupM."id"
WHERE
     message."groupId" = 'a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e'
ORDER BY message."createdAt" DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 3;

Here is the table



"id"
"groupId"
"transactionId"
"createdAt"




1
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
null
2024-05-03 14:45:46.881317


2
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
20d1e6a7-5cca-48bf-8ac2-ba8fb9f38772
2024-05-03 15:45:46.881317


3
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
20d1e6a7-5cca-48bf-8ac2-ba8fb9f38772
2024-05-03 15:45:46.881317


4
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
null
2024-05-03 17:45:46.881317


5
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
null
2024-05-03 18:45:46.881317



Desired result:



"id"
"transactionId"
"ids"
"createdAt"




5
null
null
2024-05-03 18:45:46.881317


4
null
null
2024-05-03 17:45:46.881317


2
a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e
{2, 3}
2024-05-03 15:45:46.881317



The main idea is to group rows with transactionId and count groups as one row, but don't aggregate rows with transactionId IS NULL. So from 2 rows with transactionId and 2 rows with null, LIMIT 3 should return one grouped by transactionId, and 2 with null.
But on large tables, it works very slow. How can I improve it?

i can not see any column that is called batch id

Sorry, I got the name wrong. I meant transactionId

The query is too complex, even with sample data ot will be difficult, you should rewrite the subquery so that it groups only by transactionId but that is only a suggestion, without seeing the table and the data it is not really possible to do a suggestion

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Your query is quite complex and I'm not sure what you mean by "handle rows  with same batchid as a single row"? GROUP BY springs to mind, but I can't be sure. Please go to dbfiddle.uk and provide a simplified fiddle with some sample data and your desired result.

Hi, thanks, i edited first message

Null values are treated as equal by GROUP BY, so those rows would be aggregated, too.  See:

How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns? - last chapter

Break out null cases to keep them separate, and only aggregate not-null cases. UNION ALL the full 3 latest rows from each to be sure - meaning the sum of LIMIT + OFFSET. (Doesn't add much cost for a small number.) Apply ORDER BY, OFFSET & LIMIT in the outer SELECT again:
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT "transactionId", "createdAt"
     , null::uuid[] AS ids
     , id
FROM   message
WHERE  "groupId" = 'a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e'
AND    "transactionId" IS NULL
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC, id  -- added id tiebreaker
LIMIT  3  -- no OFFSET
)
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT "transactionId", "createdAt"
     , array_agg(id) AS ids
     , any_value(id) AS id  -- pg 16+, see below!
FROM   message
WHERE  "groupId" = 'a5086f93-7e62-47ea-9419-6e3800b2a15e'
AND    "transactionId" IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY "transactionId", "createdAt"
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC, id  -- added id tiebreaker
LIMIT  3  -- no OFFSET
)
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC, id  -- added id tiebreaker
OFFSET 0
LIMIT  3;

To make it fast, have at least a multicolumn index on ("groupId", "createdAt") - with fields in this order.
Possibly another partial index for null cases if those are rare.
The odd construct min(id::text)::uuid AS id indicates id is actually type uuid (which has no > / < operators, hence doesn't allow min()), and this is your way to pick one arbitrary value from the set.
Postgres 16 added the convenient aggregate function any_value() for that task precisely. Fall back to your construct in older versions, or use first() from the additional module first_last_agg. See:

PostgreSQL equivalent to Oracle's ANY_VALUE(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST ORDER BY ...)

"createdAt" may not be unique, making the sort order non-deterministic and results arbitrary (possible alternating between calls). Add tiebreaker(s) to get deterministic results.
Aside:
Use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers if at all possible. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?

